# Create an array in javascript of custom objects

Tags: javascript

Hi I need some help with javascript.

```
function PricingData(id,method,freq,service,price) {
            this.ID=id;
            this.PaymentMethod_ID=method;
            this.PaymentFrequency_ID=freq;
            this.Service_ID=service;
            this.Price=price;
        }
```

I need to create an array in this way.

```
var temp=new PricingData[]{new PricingData(1,2,3,4,5),new PricingData(1,2,3,4,5)};
```

but this doesn't work. I'm going to pass the data in through the server so I would prefer syntax similar to this

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by pass the data in through the server, but I'd suggest you may want to look at json. http://www.json.org/ You may also want to look at jquery for transferring your data between the server and browser  jquery.Ajax()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use array literal notation to create an array:

```
var tmp = [new PricingData(1,2,3,4,5), new PricingData(1,2,3,4,5)];
```

For more information about arrays have a look at [MDC - Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: just out of curiosity, when an array is declared like this, how do you reference it?

Comment: @david: `tmp` is a reference to the array. `tmp[i]` gives you the `i`th element. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Ah - sort of, I meant as in can I do $var price= tmp[i].Price (to return the price), thank you

Comment: @David: Yes, you can do that (if you remove the `$`, it's not PHP ;))

Comment: how to create this one dynamicaly ?

Comment: @VeeKayBee: What do you mean? Do you want to add elements to an existing array? How this can be done should be explained in every good tutorial. E.g. have a look at the [MDN JavaScript Guide - Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Answer (score 4):

just put the new object right between the square brakcets

```
var arr = [new whatever(), new whatever()];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how to create an array of custom object by using this syntax:

var myObjArr = new Array(new PricingData(1,2,3,4,5), new PricingData(1,2,3,4,5));

or

var myObjArr = [new PricingData(1,2,3,4,5), new PricingData(1,2,3,4,5)];